# How to check if an object has a function? (DoJo)

Tags: javascript, dojo

```
var testObj = this.getView();
```

How can I check with DoJo (or just native JS) if testObj has `callableFunction` before I actually try to call `callableFunction()` and fail if it isn't there? I would prefer a native-DoJo solution as I need this to work on all browsers.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can call it like this:

```
testObj.callableFunction && testObj.callableFunction();
```

or in details:

```
if (typeof testObj.callableFunction == 'function') {
    testObj.callableFunction();
}
```

Comment: @Ethan In the his case it's safe to use == since typeof operator always returns string type. But if you use === in the project then for consistency sake — yes.

Comment: @dfsq Thanks for clarifying. So, if we need to check for non existence, we can comfortably do == "undefined".

Answer (score 4):

dojo has a function that you can use to perform the test.

```
require(["dojo/_base/lang"], function(lang){

  var testObj = this.getView();
  if(lang.isFunction(testObj.callableFunction)){
    testObj.callableFunction();
  }

});
```

Answer (score 3):

You should test that the property exists and is a function:

```
var returnFromCallable = typeof testObj.callableFunction === 'function' &&
    testObj.callableFunction();
```